# python script for keyword match between two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I want to create a pre-processing function that does a keyword match based on data given in an excel sheet.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

#text1 = "text string for keyword match"
#text2 = "hello world"
# single row dataframe
stri = [["ABC", "text string for keyword match"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(stri, columns = ['Name', 'Subject'])

#Sample keyword excel file converted to dataframe

kwlist = [['File', 'startswith', 'A1'],['sample', 'startswith', 'B2'],['text', 'startswith', 'C3'],['earth', 'contains', 'D4'],['world', 'contains', 'E5']]
km = pd.DataFrame(kwlist , columns =['keyword', 'Process', 'label'])
```

I would like to compare df with km and if the keyword matches then, based on 'Process' given in km and get the respective output 'label' from km.

I am trying with this function.

```
lists = km['keyword'].tolist()

def keymatch(text):
    for i in lists:
        p = np.where(df['Subject'].str.startswith(i) == True)[0]
        q = np.where(df['Subject'].str.contains(i) == True)
        if df['Subject'].str.contains(i).all() == True:

            if df['Subject'].str.startswith(i).all() == True:
                #p = np.where(df['Subject'].str.startswith(i) == True)[0]
                print(km['label'].iloc[p])
                print("Startswith")
            else:
                #q = np.where(df['Subject'].str.contains(i) == True)
                print(km['label'].iloc[q])
                print("Contains")
        else:
            print("use other code")

keymatch(df['Subject'].iloc[0])
```

I am always getting the output 'A1' with this.

Expected output:

E.g If the string is 'hello world'  then its process type should be contains and return an output 'E5'.

If string is 'text string for keyword match' then process should be startswith and return an output 'C3'

Comment: can you post the expected output

Comment: 'C3' for the given code

Comment: does `df` always has single row?

Comment: yes, an excel(df) with single row is the input for now.

Answer (score 2):

Not an efficient solution but this will work

```
res = km.loc[km.apply(lambda x: any(x.keyword in y for y in df.Subject), axis=1), 'label']
print(res)
```

**Output:**

```
2    C3
Name: label, dtype: object
```

For example `df` like this

```
  Name                        Subject
0  ABC  text string for keyword match
1  XYZ                    hello world
```

It will give output

```
2    C3
4    E5
Name: label, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But It gives the output even when a word with Process startswith is even present in the middle of the string.  
E.g "string for text keyword match script" would still return  C3, but output should be empty.

Comment: then  you should create new datframe using `km` and `df` based on `Process` column